# How to decode Base64Encoded Bytes to Image in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I want to convert a bas64 string to an image. Here's the code I currently have.

```
let sData = success as! String
let str = String(utf8String: sData.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: str!, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0) )
let image = UIImage(data: decodedData! as Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: (yourBase64Dasta as? String)! , options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {

        imgThumb = UIImage(data: decodedData)

}
```

this is currently working code in my swift 4 project so you can use it :)

Comment: @DadaTagore have you put an exact Base64 string in the function ?? because it is perfectly working in my code :) or you give me your JASON response or BAse64 string  i will check and let you know

Comment: from server value comes like ... IHDR´´=Í2 pHYsÄÄ+ IDATxí]h×ÿ¬0wÎ'ÉrBÿ¶ÖÄ+Q×»ÙH¡½@°]¹=rrqMM²²(X
¥D»"¸ÔnV¥82Tk©ÅíE2µbzgU6Ü8Ze½«8èGð® ...... byte format

Comment: @DadaTagore try to convert your base64String to image using this website -> . https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter and if it gives you an error then your base64 string is not correctly formatted :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension you can use to easily initialize an image from a base43 string:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(base64 str: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: str),
              let data = try? Foundation.Data(contentsOf: url),
              UIImage(data: data) != nil else { return nil }
        self.init(data: data)!
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
let image = UIImage(base64: "string from your server goes here")
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer . But i get still nil ouput

Comment: @DadaTagore please enter your string on [this website](http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image) to verify the string is an actual image and report back.

Comment: @DadaTagore what's your findings?